# Finding the center of mass of a quadrilateral in the plane

Tags: calculus, geometry

Find the center of mass of quadrilateral with vertices $(0,0), (1,2), (3,7), (2,5)$ First off I am having trouble seeing what exactly is going on in this picture since it is so small. I computed the area to be exactly 1 of this quadrilateral now how do I find the center of mass?

Comment: If you just want a number, you can use this [formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroid#Centroid_of_polygon).

Answer (score 3):

In general, the solution comes from the formula given by achille hui. Here however, we can make use of symmetry. Noticing that your four points make a (quite thin) parallelogram, we realize that the balancing point must lie at the average of the $x$ coordinates and the average of the $y$ coordinates. It's not too hard to see in a picture:

[image: parallelogram]

Hence the center of mass is at $(1.5,3.5)$.